# Current user as a comment's autor (DJANGO)

Tags: django, python-3.x, foreign-keys

I have create a model called 'Comentario' where the logged user can create his own comment. How can I do to automatically save as the author of the comment the logged user. Here I show my schema:

models.py

```
class Comentario (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, editable=False, blank=True)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.titulo)
```

views.py

```
class ComentarioCreate (LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comentario
    form_class = ComentarioForm
    template_name = 'home/comentario_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy ('home:listar')

    def save(self):
        autor=self.request.user.username
        user.save()
```

forms.py

```
class ComentarioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Comentario

        fields = [
            'titulo',
            'texto',
            'tag',
        ]
        labels = {
            'titulo': 'Titulo',
            'texto' : 'Descripcion',
            'tag' : 'Etiquetas',
        }
        widgets = {
            'titulo':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'texto':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),        
            'tag':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

Perfil is a model which inherits form AbstractUser.
models.py
    class Perfil(AbstractUser):
        nom_puesto = models.ForeignKey(Puesto, blank = True)

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.username)
```

How can I do to have in the field 'autor' the username of the logged user?

thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The method to override is `form_valid`, not save; see [models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) which explains exactly what to do.